# What is Kafoor and How Muslims use this?

Tags: fiqh, death

I want to know that what is "Kafoor" ?
How "Kafoor" put on Maiyyat ?How Muslims use it? Is this also used in other Madhaaib?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Camphor is a white colored material that is used to take things away from the smell. It is also flammable abd waxy. It is getting from camphor laurel tree these trees are common in Indonesia.
Camphor is used in the whole world not only by Muslims but in different foams like prickly heat powder and the other bam or tubes. 
Muslims using it on funeral put camphor on the dead body after washing it according to there Islamic rules like
during the last wash camphor is added into the water. Its a white and waxy material as i tell you in the shape of small cubes that keeps the body soft.